# Error de postgresql no me puedo conectar por pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, windows10, pgadmin

Buenas estoy trabajando con postgresql y se presenta un problema por q despues de instalar en win 10 postgresql y pgadmin, quiero entrar desde otro equipo a traves de pgadmin cosa que lo hago normal con otros equipos no me admite me sale el error "Unable to connect to server:" y "timeout expired".
Explico con mas detalle instale postgresql en uno de mis equipos con win 10, con el ip estatico 192.168.0.3, todo normal creo un base de datos de prueba con sus tablas antes ese equipo tenia win 7 y tenia su postgres al cual podia entrar desde mi equipo que tiene el ip 192.168.0.5 a traves de pgadmin, ahora q lo reinstale con win 10 hice la misma configuracion y no puedo entrar me sale el mensaje de arriba, configure igual el archivo pg_hba.conf. ahora subo la configuracion que tenia antes con la cual funcionaba.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/24            md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     all                                     md5
#host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Toda la configuracion es la misma talves pase por alto alguna otra configuracion si alguien hizo alguna ves esa instalacion me vendria bien un poco de ayuda gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Primero necesitas configurar PostgreSQL para escuchar peticiones remotas. Busca el archivo `postgresql.conf`, podría estar en `C:\PostgreSQL\data\` o en la misma ubicación que `pg_hba.conf`.

Contenido de: `postgresql.conf`

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0' # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                             # comma-separated list of addresses;
                             # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                             # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                  # (change requires restart)
```

Los cambios a realizar aquí son dos:

1. Cambiar la IP estática por `'0.0.0.0'` o por `'*'` para permitir ejecución desde conexiones remotas
2. Cambia el puerto por el que deseas usar

Para permitir acceso desde cualquier otro equipo (IP4 o IP6), asegúrate de tener en `pg_hba.conf` las dos siguientes líneas, de preferencia, al final del archivo:

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

Reinicia el servicio.

Ahora solo falta verificar que el Firewall permita el acceso, abriendo el puerto correspondiente.

1. Ve a Panel de Control -> Sistema y Seguridad -> Firewall de Windows Defender
2. A la izquierda, haz clic en Configuración avanzada
3. En la lista de la izquierda selecciona Reglas de entrada
4. A la derecha, selecciona nueva regla

Sigue los pasos y llena los campos con la siguiente información:

- Tipo re regla: Puerto
- TCP o UDP: TCP
- Puertos locales: 5432
- Acción: Permitir la conexión
- Marca las 3 opciones de redes: Dominio, pública y privada
- Nombre: "PostgreSQL entrada"

Solo asegúrate de poner el mismo puerto que configuraste en `postgresql.conf`. Guarda la nueva regla y ya deberías poder conectar desde otros equipos sin problema.